# Socket IO Logging: Got Message 3 in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm putting together a simple application that uses Socket IO. The scenario works E2E but I'm seeing intermittent behavior when I'm on a poor connection. In these cases I get the "connect" event which usually means that I'm connected, but when I emit, nothing is sent or received from server. I turn on `.log(true)` in my `SocketIOClient` and I get lots of debug messages one of which is

> Socket Engine Got Message: 3

I dug through the socket docs and [code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) and haven't been able to find any refs that to what these error messages mean. In the SocketEngine file I found something referencing 3 as "Bad Request" but I am listening on the "error" event and haven't been getting any errors either.

I have two main questions:

1. Best Practices on debugging and putting proper logic into Socket IO so that I know when I'm really connected or not.
2. Debugging these log event codes (3, 2, ect...). I assume they are giving me important info about what is going on, but I'm not sure what the mapping is.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find any proper solution?

Answer (score 1):

This log means that you got "pong" response, after sending a "ping".
ping should be shown as:
LOG SocketEngine: Sending ws:  as type: 2
in your log.